# Let two objects stick together while manipulating with bones

Tags: bones

I created a dragon in Blender and wanted to move on rigging it. I have the body (wing bones) and wing skin separate. When I move the bone wing skin and wing bone disconnect.

[image: Wing]

What is the easiest way to prevent that?

---

(Some works with weight paint, but I wanna know if there is a more reliable method)
Thank you

Comment: you should try and connect the bones with the skin, not keep them separate.